# Accessing object property named with dollar sign in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I have a JSON (array of objects) obtained via `Invoke-RestMethod` and I try to iterate trough them using foreach.
The property I'm interested to use as a filter is named "$value" and I cannot change this, being a COTS application.

```
foreach($item in $Result.value) {
        if ($item.properties.threadType) {
            Write-Host $item.properties.threadType
            if ($item.properties.threadType.$value -eq "1234567") {
                Write-Host $item.id
            }
        }
    }
```

Output of `Write-Host $item.properties.threadType`, `if` statements evaluates as false.

```
@{$type=System.String; $value=18792098}
@{$type=System.String; $value=N/A}
@{$type=System.String; $value=1234567}
```

Snippet of that JSON:

```
    ...
    "properties": {
        "threadType": {
            "$type": "System.String",
            "$value": "1234567"
        }
    },
    ...
```

How can I access `$value` property?
I've tried using

1. `$item.properties.threadType.$value`
2. `$item.properties.threadType.value`
3. even `$item.properties.threadType['$value']`

Comment: Try enclosing the property name in single quotes.  e.g. `$item.properties.threadType.'$value' -eq "1234567"`

Comment: You are correct, don't know why I didn't tried it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use quotation marks to qualify a member name - in this case you'll want to use single-quotes to avoid expansion of `$value` as a variable expression:

```
if ($item.properties.threadType.'$value' -eq "1234567") { <# ... #> }
```

Comment: Thank you! boxdog was the one who illuminated me with this gotcha, but I will close this and accept the answer.